# How to disable a bootstrap div which uses button class

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to disable a bootstrap div which uses button class. Button to be disabled using javascript based on some conditions

This is my code for button which is to be disabled using js:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info col-sm-3">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" ></i>
        <br>
        Send
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: disabled works on components such as select,input etc for elements such as div and span you can add a class and set via css pointer events none

Answer (score 2):

The div can be hidden in this way---

```js
$('.zz').css('display', 'none');
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
  </head>

    <body>
     <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified zz" id="btn-disable">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-info col-sm-3">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" ></i><br>
                Send
              </a>
            </div>  
</body>
  </html>
```

If you want to hide the div with onclick event you can do it in this way--

```js
              $('.zz').click(function(){
              $('.zz').css('display', 'none');
            });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
  </head>

    <body>
     <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified zz" id="btn-disable">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-info col-sm-3" >
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" ></i><br>
                Send
              </a>
             </div> 
</body>
  </html>
```

**NOW IN THIS WAY YOU CAN DISABLE IT**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         
  </head>

    <body>
     <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified zz" id="btn-disable">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-info col-sm-3" >
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" ></i><br>
                Send
              </a>
              <script type="text/javascript">
              $('.zz').click(function(){
             $(".zz *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
            });
   
          </script>
       </div>
</body>
  </html>
```

As you are just beginning with js and xml.

[This example can be helpful](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2)

Now if you want to disable the button based on some value do it like this--

**NOTE**
this just a rough way to give you some idea.
In this example you have two value `hi` and `bye` which are coming from your `xml` and getting displayed on the `HTML` page. So based on that value you are disabling the div.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
  </head>

    <body>
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified zz2" id="btn-disable2">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-info col-sm-3" >
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" ></i><br>
                bye
              </a>
        </div>
     <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified zz1" id="btn-disable1">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-info col-sm-3" >
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" ></i><br>
                hi
              </a>
       </div>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                var node = document.getElementById('btn-disable2');



textContent = node.textContent;
                alert($.trim(textContent));
             if ($.trim(textContent) == 'bye') {
             $(".zz2 *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
            }
                
   
       var node1 = document.getElementById('btn-disable1');



textContent1 = node1.textContent;
                alert($.trim(textContent1));
             if ($.trim(textContent1) == 'bye') {
             $(".zz1 *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
            }
                   </script>
       
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: 1. see, i have fetched some values from xml in js, now i want them to display those values in other html page which is being designed in bootstrap. i m a beginner to javascript.                                                                    2. based on some conditions in js file i have to disable this button which i mentioned here. so i want to knw hw i can i show that the button is disabled for certain values.

Comment: @user7455856: mention the conditions i can't see any in your question.

Comment: conditions are only to check if valid user or not. for some users i have to enable this button for some i have to disable. thats it.

Comment: how i can pass the fetched xml data from js file to another html page?

Comment: @user7455856: I have edited my answer hope this will help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
  document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].style.pointerEvents = "none";
  var timestampArray = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

    for(var i = (timestampArray.length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        timestampArray[i].style.pointerEvents = "none";
    }
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owojevLt/)